# Basic USB-C circuit not working as expected - no 5V

Tags: usb-c

I'm having issues with a board with USB-C not being powered. I've simplified everything back to basics to try confirm my understanding. I have a [USB-C breakout board](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/saiko-systems-ltd/BRK-USB-CPV3-0/15283090), I've wired 2 10k's in parallel (didn't have any 5k1 to hand, but is within 10% so should be ok), wired between CC1 and Ground and CC2 and Ground. Plugged into my [laptop](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/laptop-computers-2-in-1-pcs/mobile-precision-7760-build-your-own/spd/precision-17-7760-laptop/xctop7760emea_vivp#features_section), [laptop dock](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/dell-performance-dock-wd19dcs/apd/210-azbw/pc-accessories) and two different USB C chargers (generic one and [this Spigen](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Spigen-ArcStation-Charger-included-Charging/dp/B0998Y231K/)), I don't get 5V on VBUS on any of them.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the USB C standard if you want to see power.

You followed the standard for a receptacle, but you are working with a plug.

You have a plug, which means you need to wire a single CC pin (not both) to ground via a 5.1k resistor (20% or better). Your 2 x 10k in parrallel will work fine here)

Comment: Thanks @Ferrybig, that's kicked the breakout board into action. I have the receptacle version on order. The issue I was trying to resolve is my board, with receptacle, fitted with the two 5k1 resistors, I see three spikes at 5V then it settles to 0.4V but I'll verify my setup with the new breakout then create a new question with the relevant details.

Comment: @epac-tom If you have 2 of those plug breakout boards, wire them directly like an USB C to C cable (eg connect A1,B1,A12 for GND, connect A4, B4, A9, B9 for VBUS, A6 for D+, A7 for D- and A5 for CC). That way you can probe each signal pin

Comment: So I hooked up the two breakout boards, as suggested (well I didn't bother with all the grounds and VBus, and I'm not running firmware has enabled the USB so D+ and D- we also skipped) and it works. So is the issue is now narrowed down to one cable (of 3 so I'm ordering a few more to test with), this is the culprit Startech USB31CC50CM, which I believe should work like any other I am testing (I believe the rest are USB 2.0 though).

Comment: One common cause for a device only powering with USB C2C 2.0  cables is yet another violation of the USB C standard, instead of using 2 5.1K resistors, they join both CC lines together and use a single 5.1K resistor. Your USB 3.0 cable contains a a resistor and a chip in the cable pulling the normally unused VCONN line strongly to ground. This was also an issue with the raspberry PI 4: https://bartlomiej-klocek.medium.com/fix-your-raspberry-pi-4b-usb-c-cable-issue-at-home-45b68f9a8514